# How does R fit the first observed point, arima?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have an ARIMA(3,0,2) fit of `x` - when I set `est=fitted(fit)` I would assume that the first point of `x` and first point of `est` are equal, since there is no data before the first point to estimate. Actually, I would assume the first 3 points of `x` being equal to `est`due to the AR(3) part.

Why is that not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the first values of `x` and `est` are not supposed to be equal. The function `fitted` returns a h-step forecast and the default value of `h` is 1. So in your case the values of `est` are 1-step predictions.

It is true that the estimation of the first values of the time series is not straight forward, since they cannot be predicted based on previous observations. 
Information about how the first values of the time series are estimated can be found here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205897/how-to-compute-estimate-for-the-first-time-series-value-using-arima-model?rq=1

It seems the first values are treated as parameters and are then estimated by maximum likelihood estimation.